# How to prove Kelly criterion maximizes wealth compared to other betting strategies, and how to generalize such a proof

Tags: mathematical-economics, wealth, proof

The Kelly criterion approach to a betting situation basically involves maximizing the expected logarithm of one's wealth. The assumption is that maximizing the logarithm appears to inadvertently maximize one's expected gains after a large amount of time. In simulations, Kelly betting outperforms every other strategy, such as fixed betting, half-Kelly betting, all-in, etc. I have yet to see proof of this claim, and I would like to know how to do this proof because the true criterion might need be adjusted in different situations. For example, suppose, alongside betting, that a bettor gains a steady income of 100 tokens per day. Then being bankrupt should no longer be valued at -infinity since the user can simply wait a few days to earn some cash and start betting again. Thus the typical Kelly criterion no longer applies in this setting if one is looking for the optimal way to maximize expected wealth (for example, if the only bet available to a bettor with 100 tokens was to have 50% to lose 100 tokens and 50% to gain 200 tokens, Kelly criterion would say never to take this bet while in reality it is clearly optimal since even if you lose it, you could just take it the very next day), so you would need to use the proof approach to proving Kelly is optimal to find the new optimal criterion. Alternatively, if someone knows the optimal criterion to this alternate situation, that would also be helpful. The goal is to find the strategy which maximizes expected wealth after N days, where N is an arbitrarily large number.

tl;dr, how do you prove Kelly (maximizing expected log wealth) is optimal, and how does the optimal criterion change in a situation where, say, the bettor earns a fixed salary after each time step?

Comment: You can read [the original paper](https://www.princeton.edu/~wbialek/rome/refs/kelly_56.pdf). It is quite accessible. Your premise is wrong by the way, it doesn't maximize wealth.